# Warning: PDO::__construct() [pdo.--construct]: MySQL server has gone away , even with persistent connection

Tags: mysql, pdo, connection, warnings, persistent

I used PDO in my application to work with MySQL. I have set its connection persistent. But when I'm switching between my IDE and browser to test the project, sometimes I get error below:

> Warning: PDO::__construct() [pdo.--construct]: MySQL server has gone away in

It's strange for me because:

1. It happens sometimes after a successful load of web page (with no error). So I can make sure that I had the connection in some previous minutes.
2. I used persistent connection and I expect I don't lose connection to database.

Please help me.

Comment: I think this happens when mysql is not processing, serving data. some kind of idle mode

Answer (score 0):

According to [this comment on a reported bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=64549#1364921227) mysqlnd is catching the failure internally, reporting this as a warning, and then re-establishing the connection.

The only ways to suppress this warning being reported (for now) are to either:

1. use the @ operator or
2. to prevent warnings from being reported for the duration of execution of the constructor:

```
    $oldErrorReporting = error_reporting();
    error_reporting($oldErrorReporting & ~E_WARNING);
    // construct PDO instance here
    error_reporting($oldErrorReporting);
```